# Миграция БД с Sybase на MySQL

Tags: sybase, linux, миграция, база-данных, mysql

1. Каким образом лучше осуществить?
2. Какие проблемы могут возникнуть при переходе?
3. Существуют ли какие-нибудь инструменты для упрощения процесса миграции под Linux (Debian)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Миграцию лучше осуществлять с помощью специализированных средств, потому что это резко снижает риски искажения базы. Миграция базы данных включает в себя не только передачу данных, но и преобразование схемы базы данных и определенной части серверной бизнес-логики приложения в виде хранимых процедур.
2. Неполная миграция, когда вручную нужно исправлять или доделывать отдельные моменты перехода, как следствие высокая трудоемкость и большие трудозатраты перехода. Неполная совместимость приложения и новой базы, при которой приложение нужно частично переделывать.
3. Есть SQLWays ([Migrating Sybase to MySQL](http://www.ispirer.com/products/sybase-to-mysql-migration)) - программа по переносу (существует триальная версия с ограничениями на бизнес-логику); есть [Microsoft Data Transformation Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx) - средства по извлечению, преобразованию и внесению данных в разнородные базы; есть [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) - программа, позволяющая проводить экспорт-импорт данных в разных форматах между разными базами.